# Google maps API console.log(stateClicked)

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

LOST IN THE MAPS API...

I need to be able to interact with an existent Google map of the US. When a state is clicked on, I would like to pass its state name to a function which does some dynamic stuff based on the state that was actually clicked (shows or hides features belonging to that clicked region). I read a few related posts and searched else where however I have come up empty handed. Hope someone can help! Sorry I do not have any code to go off for this one...

Comment: You mean like this? http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_us_states_simple.html

Comment: yes exactly like that, thank you!

Comment: Do I need to use KML just to get the name of the State clicked on? Can I use just JS to pull in the name of region clicked?

Comment: No you don't need to use KML, you can do it a number of ways (like with the geocoder), depends on your level of comfort with the API, but you didn't give me a lot to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options to your question.

1. **Use KML.** 
   To do this get KML for US states and apply it. I guess you have already looked on it.
2. **Use Mouse Event and get Latitude and Longitude**

I hope following code might help you:

```
var geocoder;
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click', function(evt) {
    var lat = evt.latLng.lat();
    var lng = evt.latLng.lng();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     if (results[1]) {
       console.log(results[1].formatted_address);  //THIS IS YOUR RESULT!!!!
     } else {
       alert('No results found');
     }
    } else {
     alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
    });

}
```

The actual response you get is this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingResponses
You can find all your necessary details from here, like state in your case.

If you have any doubt, shoot.
Regards,
Suyash